# How I can give a description for an AMI image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I want to have instance-id and creation in the description of an AMI image. Is there any way by which I can create a description of the AMI image in boto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example below. Hope this helps.

```
import datetime
instance_id = instance.id
current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
date_stamp = current_datetime.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
mydescription= instance.id + date_stamp
create_ami = instance.create_image("my_ami", description=mydescription, no_reboot=True, dry_run=False)
```

Comment: When I am retrieving the value of "current_datetime" it shows the output like this: datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 17, 11, 0, 20, 772516). I want something like this '04/17/2015'